# Eclipse closes randomly all the time in Kubuntu

Tags: android, eclipse

I installed the last Ubuntu available, downloaded the KDE desktop and downloaded the Android SDKfrom the Android website.

The problem is that sometimes Eclipse closes itself,randomly. I tried re-downloading but it keeps happening.

Sometimes it happens whenever I click a cancel button (I open a window and click cancel, it clicks the whole program).
Sometimes when I delete a project.
Etc...

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to mmeyer's answer: If you want a nicer look and feel than Raleigh you can install the package `gtk2-engines-xfce` and then `export GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Xfce/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`.

Xfce is a nice look and feel and fits quite well into KDE I think. And it won't crash Eclipse.

In case you want to adjust the font, create a file `gtkrc` in your `eclipse` folder:

```
style "eclipse" {
        font_name = "Ubuntu 8"
}
class "GtkWidget" style "eclipse"
```

and add the path to `gtkrc` to `GTK2_RC_FILES`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to a Java Swing & GTK bug that I ran into when trying out 14.04 a while ago. I dont think there has been a fix but there is a work around by setting GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Raleigh/gtk-2.0/gtkrc ... works but looks ugly next to all that KDE sexiness.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1241101